# How to use copyIndex in a nested template resource?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-servicebus-topics

Big picture: I want to use the ARM template to create multiple topics on a service bus.

Known fact: The app service that deploys the template is in a different resource group than the service bus.

**Pain point: I'm using a nested template because I'm trying to create resources (topics) that are *external* to the targeted resource group. Within this nested template, I'm not sure how to get copy to work correctly.**

From [this MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple) , I believe my syntax is correct.

This is how my parameters are listed:

```
        "sharedResourcesResourceGroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "sharedResourceGroupName",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Resource Group in which platform shared resources live"
            }
        },
        "serviceBusNamespaceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "serviceBusName",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Service Bus namespace"
            }
        },
        "topics": {
            "type": "array",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "List of topics"
            },
            "defaultValue": [
                "topic1",
                "topic2"
            ]
        }
```

This is my resource object for creating the topics with the copyIndex() method:

```
 {
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'))]",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('sharedResourcesResourceGroupName')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template":{
                    "$schema": "2018-05-01",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
                            "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', parameters('topics')[copyIndex()])]",
                            "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                            "properties": {},
                            "copy": {
                                "name": "topics",
                                "count": "[length(parameters('topics'))]"
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')]"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }     
            }
        }
```

I am testing the arm template deployment using the Azure Powershell with these commands:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AZContext -SubscriptionName subscriptionWhereTheAppServiceLives
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName resourceGroupWhereAppServiceLives -TemplateFile <path to template file>\azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile <path to parameters file>\azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

The error I'm getting from the Azure powershell console is:

> The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function can only be used in a resource with copy specified.

If I remove the "copy" object and replace "name" with something like `"[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/topicName')]"`, then the template is able to create ONE topic in the right service bus. But I'm looking to create multiple topics.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), copyIndex())]",
    "resourceGroup": "[parameters('sharedResourcesResourceGroupName')]",
    "copy": {
        "name": "topics",
        "count": "[length(parameters('topics'))]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName')]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
            "$schema": "2018-05-01",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics",
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceBusNamespaceName'), '/', parameters('topics')[copyIndex()])]",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-04-01",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "properties": {}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried it out and this gives a ```'The template reference 'serviceBusNamespaceName' is not valid: could not find template resource or resource copy with this name.```. I'm thinking the service bus needs to be listed as a deployment resource first...

Comment: well, I can't see your template, so I don't know if service bus is in the same template, but it definitely should not be inside the nested template. anyway, you should accept this answer :)

Comment: This should be the answer. You need to move the copy section out if you are in a nested template, because the resource itself can't look, the whole nested template has to loop.

Comment: i think they have full mode now, where nested template can have copies inside